# Source of OpenJDK 11 (incl. bug/security fixed versions)

Tags: openjdk-11, sles

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 contains OpenJDK 11. Is that the OpenJDK published by Oracle from https://openjdk.java.net/ or AdoptJDK or which one? What is the source for bug and security fixed versions for that OpenJDK 11 in SLES 15?

## Update

(22.05.2021)

The last build for JDK 11 on https://jdk.java.net/archive/ is 11.0.2+9:

[image]

In SLES 15 the last build seems to be 11.0.**11**. Thus, several changes seem to have been included into this version in contrast to the 11.0.2 (from java.net). So, my question is still open: Where do they get this version from? They are unlikely to fix bugs and security problems themselves.

Comment: They are all the same thing (pretty much) .

Comment: No, I think you can't get a fixed OpenJDK 11.0.11 from openjdk.java.net (Oracle) without paying for a license for example. So, what is the source of fixed OpenJDK versions in SLES?

Comment: That is a different issue entirely.  (The fact that you pay doesn't alter what you get.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the package information based on the repository data:

```
zypper if java-11-openjdk
```

or query the RPM package directly:

```
rpm -qpi java-11-openjdk-11....rpm
```

This will output the basic package information.
For example, here's the details of the package "java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0-3.56.1.x86_64" as available for SLES 15 SP2:

```
$ rpm -qpi java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0-3.56.1.x86_64.rpm     
                                                         
Name        : java-11-openjdk
Version     : 11.0.11.0
Release     : 3.56.1
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Development/Languages/Java
Size        : 637573
License     : Apache-1.1 AND Apache-2.0 AND GPL-1.0-or-later AND GPL-2.0-only AND GPL-2.0-only WITH Classpath-exception-2.0 AND LGPL-2.0-only AND MPL-1.0 AND MPL-1.1 AND SUSE-Public-Domain AND W3C
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Do 22 Apr 2021 10:03:24 CEST, Key ID 70af9e8139db7c82
Source RPM  : java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0-3.56.1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Do 22 Apr 2021 09:53:38 CEST
Build Host  : sheep69
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : https://www.suse.com/
Vendor      : SUSE LLC <https://www.suse.com/>
URL         : https://openjdk.java.net/
Summary     : OpenJDK 11 Runtime Environment
Description :
The OpenJDK 11 runtime environment.
Distribution: SUSE Linux Enterprise 15
```

To answer your questions in short, the following details should help:

```
Source RPM  : java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0-3.56.1.src.rpm 
URL         : https://openjdk.java.net/
```

SUSE provides a source RPM package for your installed package.